# C# type or namespace expected confusion

Tags: c#, types, namespaces

Im getting slightly confused by a C# error.

`Type t = thing.GetType()`

`t` is now a type. but if i attempt to do this:

`new GenericThing<t>`

I get a warning saying type or namespace expected. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is a Type object created at runtime. Generics expect a type name, resolved at compile time. To create a generic at runtime, you have to use [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)

For example:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericThing<>).MakeGenericType(t));
```

Answer (score 2):

`t` is an object instance of type `Type`, i.e. something that only exists at runtime. Generics work at compile time and expect the name of the type.

I think you agree that the following doesn't make sense:

```
Type t = thing.GetType()
TypeOfThing instance = new t();
```

And for the same reason, you can't pass a type instance as the parameter of a generic.

Answer (score 1):

`Type` is a class that *represents* a type rather than actually *being* one, so you cannot use an instance of `Type` in a place that expects a type or type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this :

```
var youGeneric = typeof(GenericThing<>).MakeGenericType(t)
                                       .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
                                       .Invoke(null);
```