# Calling a method with a dynamic return type using a Type object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dynamic, methods

Say I have a method defined as follows:

```
public T InvokeMethod<T>(string serviceName, string methodName, params object[] args)
```

Say I want to invoke it with a Type object as follows, it doesn't work:

```
int i = 100;
Type x = i.GetType();
invoker.InvokeMethod<x>(method.Item1, method.Item2, null);
```

I know I can invoke this method by actually specifying the type as follows, but I want it to be dynamic.

```
invoker.InvokeMethod<int>(method.Item1, method.Item2, null);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried the base type of object?

Comment: I have not fully thought this comment out, but what about an overload for each type?

Comment: What are you doing with the type. are you defining a return type?

Comment: It worked using object. Thanks!

Comment: invoker.InvokeMethod<object>(method.Item1, method.Item2, null) works. I guess I didn't fully think out how this was going to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because x isnt a type that you can use in a generic class, x is an instance of the type `Type`. This is calculated at run time. Generic classes expect a class name, calculated at compile time. This is better explained in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120375/

Fundamentally, x is an instance of a class, but in `invoker.InvokeMethod<int>`, `int` is the name of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably would not like my answer but there is not really much point using generics in WCF since all contracts must be translatable to WSDL as such you have to use `KnownType` attribute anyway.